# Is it possible to add youtube/social media links to code comments?

Tags: optimization

I think it would help explain the code better, but what do I know, I am just a newbie, an alternative would be little audio notes as code comments.
Is this allowed, possible, desirable, or I am just saying incoherent stuff here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be a lot of practical issues that would make audio notes embedded in source code problematic.

However...

You may be someone who thinks best when speaking to another person, and not someone who finds it natural to articulate their thoughts when writing. If that is the case, find out which text-to-speech converters you like best, and use them to dictate your thoughts. Then embed the text into the program source as comments.